# PowerShell prompt here

Tags: powershell

I'm using this small script from [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingPowerShellPromptHere.aspx) to append an entry to opening PowerShell from the context menu when clicking on a folder.

However, I'd like to change its behaviour in order to open the PowerShell from within a directory. Is this possible?

Regards

Comment: You might not be able to use this solution verbatim, but maybe it will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451668/bat-file-to-open-cmd-in-current-directory

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I do not see how a linux related question might help me here?

Comment: You didn't read the question very carefully. The question was about how to reproduce behaviour from a linux environment (a button click that opened a new terminal window in the directory that the button was clicked on) in a Windows environment. I think this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4461768/192801 is actually closer to what you want.

Comment: At least you can open a CMD "here".

`In Vista and Windows 7, you'll get that option if you hold down shift and right-click (this is built in).`

Does anybody know how this might be changed to use the PowerShell instead?

Comment: The technique is to find Cmdhere in the Registry.  Then add PowerShelHere and wire-up in the same way as Cmdhere.  I started at: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blatantly stealing from http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-openhere.html, you basically need to save the following to a text file with an extension of `.reg`, double click to run it and confirm the input. Now when you right click on a directory, you will have an option for "PowerShell Here".

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PSOpenHere]
@="PowerShell Here"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\PSOpenHere\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%L'"
```